# Скролл внутри pop-up на Selenium webdriver + node.js

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, тестирование

Для определенного теста на странице сайта требуется выполнить скрол в "pop-up" окне.
Всё, что смог найти для node.js это:

```
driver.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,100);');
```

Использую стандартную библиотеку для node.js [selenium-webdriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За место `window`, нужно использовать `element`, тогда, все будет работать.